# VBA - Application.EnableCancelKey is acting somehow strange

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty much the question is the following - why in the immediate window I get this:

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = 2
?Application.EnableCancelKey
1
```

The last line should be 2 or am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure about this, but I think this only indicates that your current procedure is interrupted.

Comment: When I set it in the immediate window to 2 - (xlErrorHandler)  with my first line, then why with the check on the second one it returns 1 - (xlInterrupt).

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: I think (but am not sure) that it returns `1` because the actual procedure is now interrupted. It does not write the value you set, but the value of the state it is in right now. "_ xlInterrupt 1:
The current procedure is interrupted, and the user can debug or end the procedure._"

Comment: I see what you mean @Tom, but if you open an empty excel without any macros or procedures and you write the code there it still gives what it gives. And there is no interruption there.

Comment: Well it is strange, you cannot either set it to `xlDisabled` , which you normaly woul be able to do as explained in the coumentation of Microsoft [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214566(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

The basis is that the enum `xlErrorHandler` states that "The interrupt is sent to the running procedure as an error, trappable by an error handler set up with an On Error GoTo statement.", you need an error handler to use that enum (`xlErrorHandler` or `2`).

[Since some statements are not possible within the immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278738.aspx), and `On Error GoTo` is one of these statements, you cannot have an error handler in the immediate window and thus change the value of the `EnableCancelKey` to `2`. Hence Excel switches it automaticaly to `1`, giving you the value `1` when you ask it to display the value.

The only solution would be to use a sub.

---

**Original reply:**

Ok, I used the code in the [documentation provided on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214566(v=office.11).aspx) and edited a few things to test it with the following code.

To explain shortly I stopped the execution by pressing just once the "ESC" button and thus preventing the textbox to be exited. You can watch in the  Immediate Window that the last EnableCancelKey has changed in value normaly.

```
Sub Test1()

Debug.Print " Before execution result : " & Application.EnableCancelKey

On Error GoTo handleCancel
Application.EnableCancelKey = 2 'xlErrorHandler
Debug.Print " Regular execution result : " & Application.EnableCancelKey

For x = 1 To 10000  ' Do something 1,000,000 times (long!)
    Debug.Print "Test"
Next x

handleCancel:
If Err = 18 Then
    Debug.Print "Aborted macro result : " & Application.EnableCancelKey
    MsgBox "You cancelled"
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, I got the result expected.

You have to write an [Error Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx) to get the 2 value, else the code cannot catch the error, that's why you get the 1 every time you were executing the macro.

Since the description of the enum `xlErrorHandler` states that "The interrupt is sent to the running procedure as an error, trappable by an error handler set up with an On Error GoTo statement.", you need an error handler to use that enum.

With this it should work:

```
Sub test2()

On Error GoTo theEnd
Application.EnableCancelKey = 2
Debug.Print Application.EnableCancelKey

theEnd:
End Sub
```

Comment: Uh, which results exactly? 2 and 1?

Comment: Yeah, cool, but why doesn't it change in the immediate window?

Comment: When I entered `xlDisabled` the result was `0` and I couldn't stop the macro running, when `xlInterrupt` was supplied I got `1` and the macro stopped at the exact location I stopped and when `xlErrorHandler` was supplied I got `2` and the message "You cancelled". All these results were in the Immediate window by the way.

Comment: Hi @PierreChevallier, thank you for your input. Anyway, if I remove the "On Error Goto" the edit version of your code works the same way. And yeah, the results were in the immediate window, because you make "debug.print" and thats where the results are printed. The question is why it does not take the orders from the immediate window. Usually the "Application" object takes them from there.

Comment: I edited my answer in the top edit, you'll see that this action is not possible in the immediate window.

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered if possible? Thanks in advance.